# Wants to get thumbnail of files except images in liferay

Tags: java, liferay, thumbnails

I want to get the thumbnail of all Files stored in Document and Media portlet of Liferay ,for images thumbnails i am using these  libraries

```
import com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.ImageProcessorUtil;
import com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.DLPreviewableProcessor;
```

and for getting thumbnail stream i am using this mechanism

```
InputStream thumbnail = ImageProcessorUtil.getThumbnailAsStream(f.getFileVersion(),     DLPreviewableProcessor.THUMBNAIL_INDEX_DEFAULT);
```

My problem is that i want to get the thumbnail stream of all contents stored in Liferay.Is is possible??? any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am trying to understand your question. Do you want to generate Thumbnail for contents other than Document & media? Like for WebContents, Blogs, etc?

Comment: i have uploaded files document and media portlet like doc ,text files and i want thumbnails of that files

Comment: So you want extension based thumbnails, right?

Comment: yes Rushikesh Thakkar

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is already provided by Liferay. As the [documentation](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/automatic-previews-and-metada-6) suggests, you will need to configure some 3rd party tools/libraries on your Liferay instance.

If you just want to change the default thumbnail images, then you can update your replace these images with the images of your choice at `_unstyled\images\file_system\large` and `_unstyled\images\file_system\small` in your theme.

### EDIT

To answer your last comment about previewing XML file (which I have answered on high level above, but nevertheless...):

1. Add the below property in your `portal-ext.properties` file:

   ```
   dl.file.generic.extensions[xmlimage]=xml
   ```
2. And, add `xmlimage.png` file in `_unstyled\images\file_system\large`
   and `_unstyled\images\file_system\small` in your theme.

Comment: basically i have already added third party tools in liferay ,thumbnails are now shown in Document and media portlet but the problem is that for images i am using ImageProcessorUtil class of liferay but there is not such class to get thumbnails of customs types

Comment: Would getExtension() method of  com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.DLFileEntry class help?

Comment: i am using DLFileEntry but there is no such class in liferay that would help in generating thumbails of xml like ImageprocessorUtils

Comment: I haven't come across any API to generate thumbnails for XML file, and to be honest, I wouldn't even go that route. So, if you want to show a fixed thumbnail image for xml file, then I've edited my answer to explain it. Let me know if it suffices your needs.